# Npm freezes for some time

Tags: npm, cmd, npm-install, npm-update

I have a problem. When I run any npm commands in cmd (like npm install or npm update) , my terminal sometimes freezes for 3-5 minutes like in below example.
It doesn't output anything at that time. I think it is paranormal.

So is there a way to fix that.

D:\MyAwesomeReactNativeApps\Store>npm update
[         .........] | idealTree: timing idealTree Completed in 12991ms

P.S After 5 mins it continues working and completes well.
P.P.S It always stops with this "| idealTree: timing idealTree Completed in"

Comment: I think it might just be a big package -- but yeah after 5 minutes it worked for me too, so thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: So this behaviour is normal. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be that way. I'm using WSL and you appear to be using windows as well so possibly that's why it takes longer